# Quoted separator cursor copy_from in python

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2

Is there any way to provide Quoted separator like

```
import psycopg2


f_cm = open('cm.sql', 'r')

constr = "dbname='mydb' user= 'pgsql' host='127.0.0.1'"
db = psycopg2.connect(constr)
st = db.cursor()

#st.copy_from(f_cm, 'mytable', sep='","', columns = ('col1','col2', 'col3'))
#instead of 
st.copy_from(f_cm, 'mytable', sep=',', columns = ('col1','col2', 'col3'))
```

Date format is:

```
"54654","4454","45465"
"54546","4545","885dds45"
"54536","4546","885dd45"
```

I have searched and found Good news at psycopg
[New in psycopg2.0.9](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/news.html)

Go to heading What’s new in psycopg 2.0.9¶ which states: 
copy_from() and copy_to() can now use quoted separators.

tools:

```
psycopg2 = 2.4.5
python = 2.7.3
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems Like cursor.copy_from or copy_to does not support Quoted sheets. solution is to use copy_expert.

```
import psycopg2


f_cm = open('cm.sql', 'r')

constr = "dbname='mydb' user= 'pgsql' host='127.0.0.1'"
db = psycopg2.connect(constr)
st = db.cursor()

copy = "COPY mytable(col1,col2, col3) FROM STDIN with csv"
st.copy_expert(sql=copy, file=f_cm)

db.commit()
st.close()
db.close()
```